# Why the curve twisted at one side

Tags: bezier-curves

Converting mesh to curve i have made the shape. With the circle im making a bevel shape. One end of the curve is been twisted. I have selected all the verts and set the radius to 1. Applied rotation scale. Still the curve is twisted. Any suggestion or help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **Curve Segments** are highly twisted. To correct this you can **use Twisting > Smooth** under **Curve Data** tab - **Shape section**.

[image: twist]